# Singleton constructor crashes my app

Tags: android, constructor, crash, singleton

I'm testing out the model layer of my application and I want to add an element to a list. But whenever I try to add some data into my data model the application crashes. I cannot find the reason for this.

My code for the data model.

```
public class DataModel {


private List<Log> logs;
private static DataModel instance;
private Context ctx;


//Singleton constructor
private DataModel()
{
   //This makes it crash
   logs.add(new Log("1234","sms", 123545, 1, 0));

   //Load logs from database - Not done yet.

}

public static DataModel getInstance()
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        //Creates the instance
        instance = new DataModel();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

My code for log

```
public class Log {


private String phonenumber;
private String type;
private long date;
private int incoming;
private int outgoing;
private long id;

//Constructor for incoming sms or call
public Log( String Phonenumber, String Type, long Date, int Incoming, int Outgoing)
{

    this.phonenumber = Phonenumber;
    this.type = Type;
    this.date = Date;
    this.incoming = Incoming;
    this.outgoing = Outgoing;
}


public long getId()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getPhonenumber()
{
    return phonenumber;
}

public void setPhonenumer(String phonenumber)
{
    this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
}

public String getType()
{
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type)
{
    this.type = type;
}

public long getDate()
{
    return date;
}

public void setDate(long date)
{
    this.date = date;
}

public int getIncoming()
{
    return incoming;
}

public void setIncoming(int incoming)
{

    this.incoming = incoming;

}

public int getOutgoing()
{
    return outgoing;
}

public void setOutgoing (int outgoing)
{

    this.outgoing = outgoing;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not initializing `logs`. Its `null` when you execute this statement:

```
logs.add(new Log("1234","sms", 123545, 1, 0));
```

Change:

```
private List<Log> logs;
```

to:

```
private List<Log> logs = new ArrayList<Log>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a context in your code, but you don't set it or use it anywhere so maybe you stripped part of your code. In relation to that, if you use it to UI related stuff (and some other cases) I can guarantee you that it will crash your app if you don't reset it every time the screen orientation changes or you change activities.

Answer (score 0):

You have not Instantiated list object

```
private List<Log> logs;
```

Update your constructor to this

```
//Singleton constructor
private DataModel()
{
   //This makes it crash
   logs = new ArrayList<Log>();
   logs.add(new Log("1234","sms", 123545, 1, 0));

   //Load logs from database - Not done yet.

}
```

Now every time you constructor gets called you will get a fresh copy of list object.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the List before use

you  can initialize the  List  in Constructor as well

public class DataModel {

```
private List<Log> logs= new ArrayList<Log>();
private static DataModel instance;
private Context ctx;


//Singleton constructor
private DataModel()
{
   //This makes it crash
   logs.add(new Log("1234","sms", 123545, 1, 0));


   int i=0;

   //Load logs from database - Not done yet.

}

public static DataModel getInstance()
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        //Creates the instance
        instance = new DataModel();
    }
    return instance;
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

Don't initialize globally logs and also use synchronized getInstance method so that only one instance should get created if two threads are trying to access at the same time.

Use this code:

```
public class DataModel {
    private List<Log> logs;
    private static DataModel instance;
    private Context ctx;


    //Singleton constructor
    private DataModel()
    {
       if(logs == null){
           logs = new ArrayList<Log>();
        }
       logs.add(new Log("1234","sms", 123545, 1, 0));

       //Load logs from database - Not done yet.

    }

    public synchronized static DataModel getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            //Creates the instance
            instance = new DataModel();
        }
        return instance;
    }
```